# Motion Streak for specific Sprites?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, sprite, andengine, motion

AndEngine GLES2 has an example for a full scene motion streak/blur which works great, but I would like to apply that motion blur to only specific sprites.

Kind of like I don't want my characters to motion blur, just the spells(Sprites).

This is what I am using to do a motion blur right now, it is simply the AndEngine example, but the problem is it seems to take a snapshot of the whole screen, apply an aplha, and then merge it with the next frame of the screen, and I would only like to apply this "alpha" blurring affect to individual sprites.

```
@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine(EngineOptions pEngineOptions) {
    return new Engine(pEngineOptions) {
        private static final int RENDERTEXTURE_COUNT = 2;

        private boolean mRenderTextureInitialized;

        private final RenderTexture[] mRenderTextures = new RenderTexture[RENDERTEXTURE_COUNT];
        private final Sprite[] mRenderTextureSprites = new Sprite[RENDERTEXTURE_COUNT];

        private int mCurrentRenderTextureIndex = 0;

        @Override
        public void onDrawFrame(final GLState pGLState) throws InterruptedException {
            final boolean firstFrame = !this.mRenderTextureInitialized;

            if(firstFrame) {
                this.initRenderTextures(pGLState);
                this.mRenderTextureInitialized = true;
            }

            final int surfaceWidth = this.mCamera.getSurfaceWidth();
            final int surfaceHeight = this.mCamera.getSurfaceHeight();

            final int currentRenderTextureIndex = this.mCurrentRenderTextureIndex;
            final int otherRenderTextureIndex = (currentRenderTextureIndex + 1) % RENDERTEXTURE_COUNT;

            this.mRenderTextures[currentRenderTextureIndex].begin(pGLState, false, true);
            {
                /* Draw current frame. */
                super.onDrawFrame(pGLState);

                /* Draw previous frame with reduced alpha. */
                if(!firstFrame) {
                    if(Info.motionStreaking) {
                        this.mRenderTextureSprites[otherRenderTextureIndex].setAlpha(0.9f);
                        this.mRenderTextureSprites[otherRenderTextureIndex].onDraw(pGLState, this.mCamera);
                    }
                }
            }
            this.mRenderTextures[currentRenderTextureIndex].end(pGLState);

            /* Draw combined frame with full alpha. */
            {
                pGLState.pushProjectionGLMatrix();
                pGLState.orthoProjectionGLMatrixf(0, surfaceWidth, 0, surfaceHeight, -1, 1);
                {
                    this.mRenderTextureSprites[otherRenderTextureIndex].setAlpha(1);
                    this.mRenderTextureSprites[otherRenderTextureIndex].onDraw(pGLState, this.mCamera);
                }
                pGLState.popProjectionGLMatrix();
            }

            /* Flip RenderTextures. */
            this.mCurrentRenderTextureIndex = otherRenderTextureIndex;
        }

        private void initRenderTextures(final GLState pGLState) {
            final int surfaceWidth = this.mCamera.getSurfaceWidth();
            final int surfaceHeight = this.mCamera.getSurfaceHeight();

            final VertexBufferObjectManager vertexBufferObjectManager = this.getVertexBufferObjectManager();
            for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
                this.mRenderTextures[i] = new RenderTexture(DodgingGame.this.getTextureManager(), surfaceWidth, surfaceHeight);
                this.mRenderTextures[i].init(pGLState);

                final ITextureRegion renderTextureATextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(this.mRenderTextures[i]);
                this.mRenderTextureSprites[i] = new Sprite(0, 0, renderTextureATextureRegion, vertexBufferObjectManager);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

How can I change it to work for specific sprites instead of the whole visible screen?

Comment: The answer to this question is either 'yes' or 'no'. You should show us what other research you have done, and then improve your question to make it much more specific.

Comment: Updated the question to be more specific on what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a particle system to create motion blur effect.

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking.

Comment: @adamjansch - That comment was completely unconstructive. sphinx - I did try a particle system actually, and attaching it to the sprite itself. It would work if I was not rotating the direction of the sprite, but when you rotate a particle System it rotates all of the particles, not just the particleEmitter's direction